# Interactive Ploting with Matplotlib

Tags: python, interaction, matplotlib-3d

When I adjust the position slider, for example pdfReader X,Y,Z, the point(pdfReader) in the plot won't be updated accordingly. Instead, I would see <Figure size 640x480 with 0 Axes> in my jupyter output block [image]

Here is the python code I tried.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

# Initial data
dtype_ = np.dtype('float32')

element_positions = np.array([
    np.array([0.36918038, 0.12599993, 0.5699662], dtype=dtype_),
    np.array([0.409, -0.03100002, 0.531], dtype=dtype_)
])

element_labels = ['MusicPlayer', 'PDFReader']

# Create a 3D scatter plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Create a function to update and redraw the plot
def update_plot():
    ax.clear()
    ax.scatter(element_positions[:, 0], element_positions[:, 1], element_positions[:, 2], c='r', marker='^')
    for i, label in enumerate(element_labels):
        ax.text(element_positions[i, 0], element_positions[i, 1], element_positions[i, 2], label, fontsize=8)
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')
    ax.set_title('3D Scatter Plot')
    plt.draw()

# Create sliders for updating element positions
sliders = []
for i, label in enumerate(element_labels):
    sliders.append(widgets.FloatSlider(value=element_positions[i, 0], min=-1, max=1, step=0.01, description=f'{label} X'))
    sliders.append(widgets.FloatSlider(value=element_positions[i, 1], min=-1, max=1, step=0.01, description=f'{label} Y'))
    sliders.append(widgets.FloatSlider(value=element_positions[i, 2], min=-1, max=1, step=0.01, description=f'{label} Z'))

def update_positions(change):
    for i in range(len(sliders)):
        element_positions[i // 3, i % 3] = sliders[i].value
    update_plot()

for i in range(len(sliders)):
    sliders[i].observe(update_positions, names='value')

# Display the sliders and the plot
slider_widgets = widgets.VBox(sliders)
display(widgets.HBox([slider_widgets]))
update_plot()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

what you need to do is to switch to an interactive matplotlib backend for jupyter notebooks! The recommended one here would be [ipympl](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl).

Once installed, all you need to do is to activate the backend with the magic-command (at the very top of your script)

```py
%matplotlib widget
```

and then all should work as expected!

[image]